# add paragraph style reportlab

Tags: python, pdf

I'm trying to set a paragraph style to report lab, I defined a style here:

```
def stylesheet():
    styles= {
        'default': ParagraphStyle(
            'default',
            fontName='Arial',
            fontSize=16,
            leading=12,
            leftIndent=0,
            rightIndent=0,
            firstLineIndent=0,
            alignment=TA_LEFT,
            spaceBefore=0,
            spaceAfter=0,
            bulletFontName='Arial',
            bulletFontSize=10,
            bulletIndent=0,
            textColor= black,
            backColor=None,
            wordWrap=None,
            borderWidth= 0,
            borderPadding= 0,
            borderColor= None,
            borderRadius= None,
            allowWidows= 1,
            allowOrphans= 0,
            textTransform=None,  # 'uppercase' | 'lowercase' | None
            endDots=None,         
            splitLongWords=1,
        ),
    }
```

Then I print it like that

```
   pdf = PDFDocument(carte)
    pdf.init_report()
    pdf.p(str(row))
    pdf.generate()
```

Which gives an unformatted output

When I try

```
pdf = PDFDocument(carte)
pdf.init_report()
pdf.p(str(row), default)
pdf.generate()
```

To apply the default style to my text, it gives me 'NameError: name 'styles' is not defined'

Any clue?

Comment: `Reportlab` is not the same as `PDFDocument`... `PDFDocument` is just a simplified version of `Reportlab`. The capabilities of `Reportlab` are far bigger.

Answer (score 11):

I've been struggling with this for a few hours, as of today the solution provided didn't work for me. I found another on [programcreek](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/60058/reportlab.lib.styles.ParagraphStyle) that almost did. After a little retouch this one did the trick:

```
#First you need to instantiate 'getSampleStyleSheet()'
from reportlab.lib.styles import (ParagraphStyle, getSampleStyleSheet)
style = getSampleStyleSheet()
yourStyle = ParagraphStyle('yourtitle',
                           fontName="Helvetica-Bold",
                           fontSize=16,
                           parent=style['Heading2'],
                           alignment=1,
                           spaceAfter=14)
```

To use it just call *yourStyle* like this:

```
Story.append(Paragraph("Whatever printed with yourStyle", yourStyle))
```

Alignment must be given with a number as indicated in the docs:

> There are four possible values of alignment, defined as constants in the module reportlab.lib.enums. These are TA_LEFT, TA_CENTER or TA_CENTRE, TA_RIGHT and TA_JUSTIFY, with values of 0, 1, 2 and 4 respectively. These do exactly what you would expect.

I'm posting the answer because I couldn't find a precise answer anywhere in the hope that it might help other people.

Comment: Excellent! Been hunting around for this for a good hour! Small typo on line 7, `parent=styles['Heading2'],` should be `parent=style['Heading2'],`

Comment: You are right. Just corrected it. I'm glad it was of help

Answer (score 6):

Try this with reportlab, adding to your existing code:

```
from reportlab.lib.styles import ParagraphStyle, getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_LEFT
from reportlab.lib.colors import black

styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
styles['small'] = ParagraphStyle(
   'small',
    parent=styles['default'],
    fontSize=8,
    leading=8,
)

paragraphs.append(Paragraph('Text with default style<br/>', styles['default']))
paragraphs.append(Paragraph('Text with small style', styles['small']))
```

Comment: What is styles and where came from? styles['default'] could not be found. Do we have to created it?

Comment: I get like this:`from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet... styles = getSampleStyleSheet()`